# "Illegal characters in path" while cloning with git from Visual Studio 2017

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017

On Visual Studio 2017, I can not clone a repository with git.
I'm having this error message:

[image]

The repository url is good and the destination folder is also fine (no spaces or special characters).
I tried on another computer and everything works perfectly.
When I'm cloning the same project with GitKraken, SourceTree or in command line, everything works.
I tried to uninstall git, cleaning  my tfs/git credentials, uncheck "Git for Windows" option on the Visual Studio installer, in vain....

Has anyone ever had the same problem? How did you solve it? Thanks for the help!

```
Visual Studio 2017: 15.9.11
Git version: 2.21.0
Git url path: https://tfs.mysubdomain.mydomain.fr/dev/PROJECT/_git/PROJECT
TFS Server: https://tfs.mysubdomain.mydomain.fr/dev/PROJECT/PROJECT%20Team/_git/PROJECT
```

Comment: pretty hard to see what might be the issue ... without seeing the full git url or path...

Comment: other git repos (some public from github) works?

Comment: I update the post. And yes I tried with some public from github and I had the same issue

Comment: For some reason could be the %20 (space) gives some unexpected issue?
Possible to try another one, from the same TFS without %20 or from github with a  %20 in it? to try and isolate the issue?

Comment: @ShaharHadas I tried with an url like this: `https://domain.visualstudio.com/Project/_git/Project`. Same issue.

Comment: What if you clone using any other tool, and then just open the project inside visual studio? It reports the issue also then?

Comment: Yes. If I clone it with another tool and open it with Visual Studio, I'm having the same issue: I cannot fetch or pull because for Visual Studio I have to clone the opened project first... Non sense. It's as if the folder was not tracked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it by this way:

- uncheck the "Git for Windows" checkbox in Visual Studio Installer
- uninstall git (for me it was version 2.21.0)
- uninstall other git apps (for me it was GitKraken and SourceTree)
- delete all git and tfs credentials via the credential manager
- reboot (just in case)
- install git
- launch visual studio and connect to the TFS server
- you can now clone and work peacefully

Et voilà :)

Everything works perfectly now. I think uninstall only git was not enough. I don't really understand why I had this issue but the bulldozer strategy was efficient.

Comment: The git version bundled with Visual Studio interfered with the standalone git version?

Comment: I don't really know because what I did before was to uncheck "Git for windows" to force Visual Studio to not use a the potential git version bundled with Visual Studio... At least I thought. I also had 2 others apps (GitKraken and SourceTree). Maybe I had some version conflicts between all these apps.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what's the cause of it. I've been running git commands in the Windows Terminal. And the same problem happened when I try to pull in Visual Studio.

Here's how I got the problem resolved:

```
Restart the computer
```

Comment: I restarted Visual Studio and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it by deleting index.lock in /git folder

Answer (score -1):

I've resolved this by deleting .\obj and .\bin folders in my startup project.